# Why is @AfterReturning is never called

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have this method and it does return a list:

```
public List<ReportReconciliationEntry> getMissingReports(List<ReportReconciliationEntry> expectedReports,
                                                              List<GeneratedReportContent> generatedReports){
        ...
        return missingReports;
    }
```

but this method is never called:

```
    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.service.ReconciliationService.getMissingReports(..)) && args(expectedReports,generatedReports)", argNames = "expectedReports,generatedReports,missingReports",  returning = "missingReports")
public void logReportReconciliationException(List<ReportReconciliationEntry> expectedReports, List<GeneratedReportContent> generatedReports, List<ReportReconciliationEntry> missingReports) {
                final String notApplicable = properties.getNotApplicable();
                ReportingAlertMarker marker = ReportingAlertMarker.builder()
                        .eventType(E90217)
                        .userIdentity(notApplicable)
                        .destinationIp(properties.getDestinationIp())
                        .destinationPort(properties.getDestinationPort())
                        .dataIdentity(notApplicable)
                        .resourceIdentity(notApplicable)
                        .responseCode(404)
                        .build();
                MDC.put(SYSTEM_COMPONENT, properties.getBpsReportGenerationService());
                System.out.println(missingReports);
                logWrapper.logError(marker, "SDGFHDZFHDFR!!");
            }
```

I check the return of the first method with a breakpoint. It does return a list, but the @AfterReturning is never called, although the IDE shows the "Navigate to AOP advices" icon. What am I missing?

This is what my class looks like:

```
   @Component
    @Aspect
    @Slf4j
    public class ReportingAlertAspect {

        private final LogWrapper logWrapper;

        private final ReportingAlertProperties properties;

        public ReportingAlertAspect(final ReportingAlertProperties properties, final LogWrapper logWrapper) {
            this.logWrapper = logWrapper;
            this.properties = properties;
        }
....
}
```

I have another class with a function in it and this one works fine:

```
        @Component
        @Aspect
        @Slf4j
        public class ReportingInfoAspect {

            private final LogWrapper logWrapper;

            private final ReportingAlertProperties properties;

      @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.xxx.yyy.zzz.qqq.ReconciliationService.reconcile(..)) && args(windowId)", argNames = "windowId,check",
                returning = "check")
        public void logSuccessfulReportReconciliation(ReconciliationEvent windowId, boolean check){
            String notApplicable = properties.getNotApplicable();
            MDC.put(SYSTEM_COMPONENT, properties.getBpsReportGenerationService());
            ReportingAlertMarker marker = ReportingAlertMarker.builder()
                    .eventType(E90293)
                    .userIdentity(notApplicable)
                    .destinationIp(properties.getDestinationIp())
                    .destinationPort(properties.getDestinationPort())
                    .dataIdentity(notApplicable)
                    .resourceIdentity(notApplicable)
                    .responseCode(200)
                    .build();
            if (check){
                logWrapper.logInfo(marker, "All reports for windowId {} were generated successfully", windowId.windowId);
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Is the AfterReturning  method called when the pointcut expression condition is minimal , say only execution ? Also confirm if the ReconciliationService is a bean and the Aspect is annotated with Aspect and Component and component scanned.

Comment: no, it is not called.

Comment: to be sure all the required steps are in place , is EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation in place ? If yes , please share the complete code of the classes relevant here.

Comment: @R.G I added the code.

Comment: To understand, 1. Are you able to advice any other method executions in your application? 2. If yes , please attempt an Around advice for this method or any other method to make sure the AOP configuration is correct. If the ReconciliationReport is a spring bean and Spring AOP setup is correct , I am unable to identify any reason why this shouldn’t work .

Comment: @R.G Yes, I am able to advice other methods. I added some code.

Comment: Did you attempt an Around advice ? Any change in behaviour ?

Comment: @R.G It was a stupid mistake. The getMissingReports was called form another method inside that class so it did never pass through the proxy. Should I just delete this question or write a response to remind people to be careful :D

Comment: Great that you identified the issue.A very common mistake when working with Spring AOP. If the code was shared in its entirety , someone would have pointed it out for you already . As per me the question will not give a full picture on the actual code that resulted in this . You may update the question and provide an answer or delete it .

Comment: @R.G thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. 
The getMissingReports method was called from another method inside the same class. This is a case of self-invocation and the method was never called through the proxy.

This is what the class looks like:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ReconciliationService {

    private final ReconciliationRepository reconciliationRepository;

    private final ReportSafeStoreClientService reportSafeStoreClientService;

    @Handler
    public whatever whatever() {
      ...
      getMissingReports()
    }

}
```

You can find more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch08s06.html)